# partial view not being rendered fron ajax call in IE 9.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an ajax call with is working fine in Mozilla and Chrome, but not in IE 9.0.  The code is as follows:

I am not able to understand why is the myDiv not being refreshed.  The save is done accordingly and it is just that the myDiv isn`t being refreshed in IE9.0.

```
$.ajax({

                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                url: "@Url.Action("Save", "Employee")",
                data:
                {
                    Id: $("#ID").val(),

                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                        $("#myDiv").html(data);                


                },
                error: function (request, status, error)
                { 
                                    }
           });
```

---

```
<div id="myDiv">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("NewPage", Model);}
        </div>
```

---

**NewPage.cshtml**

```
    @model MvcUI.Models.myModel
<div id="GridDiv">
<table>

</table>
</div>
```

---

Controller:

```
   [Authorize]
    public ActionResult NewPage( int Id)
    {
           return PartialView(new myModel(Id));
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Save(int Id)
    {

        myModel.Save(Id);
        return RedirectToAction("NewPage", new {Id = Id});

    }
```

---

**observation**
I have been doing various tests and observed the following behaviours:
In debug mode:
1.  First time I do  save, save done and table refreshed.
2. second time, the save done and table refreshed.
3.  When I do it for the 4th time, the save done, but doesnt reach ActionResult NewPage( int Id), table doesn`t refreshed but some old data displayed...!

In deployed mode:
1.  Only First time I do  save, save done and table refreshed. 
2.  Second time, it only saves but does not refresh table data!

I don`t have any error or exception.

Comment: If you put alert(error) in the error handler, does it get triggered in IE?

Comment: There is no error, it does not fall in the error function

Comment: If you use the developer tools, is the content of the page returned from the request?

Comment: I have not understood, what is the developer tools?  I am using mozilla firefox for debugging, but it is working fine in mozilla. It is only in IE that is not working.  Is there a way to test what is happening in IE?

Comment: Press F12 ... Same as firebug ...

Comment: I have edited my question with some observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the response-expiry headers? I have had issues where IE did not appear to reload the page when you do not set the following:

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
<% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```

I've put them in ASP tags, but feel free to do this in your controller if you prefer (rather than repeat it in every action, possibly create an initialisation method)

EDIT:

As per @learning's comment, one can also use the [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx#Y2400) attribute to do effectively the same thing

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
```

Comment: Ah ok great. Just looked [OutputCache()] up and seen that it effectively does the same thing, but more neatly. Glad you solved it.